# Intersection of a vector valued function and a cylinder

Tags: calculus

I've been trying to work through this problem but I'm not having any luck:

Find the points of intersection of the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 =4$
and the curve traced out by $\mathbf{F}(t)= t\cos(\pi t)\hat\imath + t\sin(\pi t)\hat\jmath + t\hat{k}$

I'd really appreciate it if someone could shed some light on this for me - thank you!

Comment: You need to solve for t by substituting $x=tcos(\pi t)$ and $y=tsin(\pi t)$ in the equation of the cylinder.

Answer (score 1):

At the intersection points the equations for the cylinder and the curve (a helix) must be solved simultaneously to get:

$$\begin{align}
x^2+y^2=(t\cos\pi t)^2+(t\sin\pi t)^2&=4  \\
    \implies    t^2(\cos^2\pi t + \sin^2\pi t)&=4 \\
    \implies    t^2&=4
\end{align}$$

This has two solutions for $t$. Plugging these values into the parametric equation for $\mathbf{F}(t)$ gives you the two points of intersection.